# Why is a lambda without any unstable variable unstable

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I trying to track down issues with a recompose that I don’t think should be happening involving a lambda.

Top level compose layout:

```
ModalBottomSheetLayout(bottomSheetNavigator) {
  NavHost(
     navController = navController,
     startDestination = "main"
  ) {
     homeGraph(
        // Nothing in this lamda and still seeing re-compose
        showSnackbar = { /* no-op */ }
     )
  }
}
```

Navigation home, which created child nav graph

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.homeGraph(
   showSnackbar: (String) -> Unit
) { 
   childGraph(
      share = { showSnackbar(it) },
   )
}
```

child graph:

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.childGraph(
   onShare: (String) -> Unit,
) {
   composable("childDetail) {
      // When a recompose happens here. I am seeing a re-componse in the DetailScreen
      // that is due to the onShare lambda
      DetailScreen(
         onShare = { onShare(it) }
      )
   }
}
```

As far as I understand if a lambda does not wrap anything that is not stable the lambda itself is remembered and not subject to re-compose.  However in this case when the childDetail composable is re-composed the DetailScreen is seeing the onShare lambda change.

This is fixed if I forcefully remember the lambda:

```
fun NavGraphBuilder.childGraph(
   onShare: (String) -> Unit,
) {
   composable("childDetail) {
      val currentOnShare = remember(Unit) { onShare }
      DetailScreen(
         onShare = { currentOnShare(it) }
      )
   }
}
```

However I don’t think that is necessary.  All of my screens have callback lambdas for different things, all with no unstable parameters wrapped.  Would be a ton of remembering lambdas...

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: Navigation causes Composables to be recomposed multiple times. It's intended behaviour. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69176617/jetpack-compose-navhost-recomposition-composable-multiple-times?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @Thracian yup I get that, its not an issue with the recompose on the navigation component.  Its an issue with recompose on the DetailScreen when nothing has changed, which is intended behaviour of compose.  The question is, why is DetailScreen recomposed based on a change to a lambda that does not have an unstable parameter.

Comment: What does the caller do in `onShare`  where its called? If there is a class that is unstable read inside where its called it becomes unstable

Comment: The caller is the very top compose layout I have shown.  It is an empty lambda right now.

Comment: Please reduce your code to [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). I've tried running your code (filling in some gaps) and I don't see any unexpected recompositions with the latest Compose (**Bom 2023.10.01**). In general, you shouldn't care about the number of recompositions, they're pretty lightweight if you build your composables in the right way, do you experience any lags?