Jetpack compose type-safe navigation - navigate usage
I`m still learning Jetpack Compose and now trying to migrate from string-based routes navigation to new APIs following this article.
Before I used something like:

@Composable
fun HomeScreen(
   ...
   navHostController: NavHostController
   ...
) {
...
   if (state.logoutRequired) {
       navController.navigate(Screen.Auth)
    }
...
}


in my screens composables. Now it leads to frame skips and visual glitches when navigating. I solve it by using LaunchedEffect, but still haven't figured out why it works that way.
So why I can navigate from LaunchedEffect, onClick, onDismiss, from other callback functions and can`t from the composable functions body?

Because navigate causes your Screen to be called multiple times. If you add navController.navigate(Screen.Auth) to function body it will be called multiple times. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69176617/jetpack-compose-navhost-recomposition-composable-multiple-times, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69190119/jetpack-compose-recompose-with-success-state-twice-when-exiting-current-composab

Move your logic to button onClick, or function lambda or something else, because composable can call anytime.

The issue that you describe is not related to the navigation library. It's related to Compose and recomposition.
If you update the state very often:

Composable functions might be re-executed as often as every frame,
such as when an animation is being rendered.

So, if you write you code right inside the Composable it will executes each time when recomposition happens.
I would suggest you to read official article Thinking in Compose, especially part related to recomposition. If you really want to understand the reason.
